# Embedded Java DB in Netbeans

Tags: java, database, netbeans, embedded-database

I have nearly finished a project developing a simple image catalogue application using Java and Netbeans.

I have only now realised that my database is not embedded so when I create the JAR file and try to run it (external to Netbenas) i get an error (error connecting to localhost).

This is the code at present that connects to the database. All works fine when run in Netbeans.

```
//conect to database
            String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Catalogue";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(host);
```

My question is (and I can't seem to find a simple solution) is there a way to just create a new embedded DB with the same name and table and rows etc and then just adjust the code so when i run the JAR file externally to Netbeans all will work OK?

I am imagining the code will be something like:

```
String host = "jdbc:derby:'path to db'/Catalogue;
```

Am I on the right track? I have tried this (I think) but it does not seem to work…

Thanks for any assistance

<<<<<< UPDATE >>>>>>>

I have now created an embedded database and created a table (named photos) with exactly the same details as my original (non-embedded) database.

I have changed the connection in the code to be:

```
String host = "jdbc:derby:catalogueEmbed;create=true";
```

Now when I run the program in Netbeans it says: "Table/view PHOTOS does not exist"

Do I need to run and sql statement in my code to create the table and row data?

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: Take a look at [Setting up an embedded Derby database in a standalone Java application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393385/setting-up-an-embedded-derby-database-in-a-standalone-java-application)

Comment: Thanks - I had seen that one already. I have made some changed in my original post… Thanks